# How to find an appropriate Stack Exchange site for my question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question that I have asked in many Stack Exchange sites and it got deleted there, its format is the one that I am providing here:

> Title: How to help a postgraduate student to write a book?
>
> Body:
>   What is the best way to help a weak student who has already completed
>   her post-graduation but has also secured a result much worser than her
>   expected result during the completion of graduation, to write a good
>   quality book which shall be recommended to higher secondary level
>   students after it gets released.

Can you please suggest which Stack Exchange site this question can fit into?

Comment: I think this question would be too broad and/or too likely to attract opinion-based answers for any SE site that I can think of. If [academia.se] is a site that has already closed it then I think you tried your "best" option.

Comment: I see that you have not yet taken the [Tour] here to learn how this site works, and you do not appear to even have an account on [academia.se] so, if you decide to open one, then you should start by taking [its Tour](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tour) too.  I do not have sufficient reputation on [academia.se] to undelete questions there, and this certainly does not look like one that I would consider undeleting even if I could.  It is too broad and too likely to result in opinion-based answers (if any).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You've posted this question multiple times on Academia.SE, and each time, other users asked you to clarify your question. For example, [on this copy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/49696/how-to-help-a-postgraduate-student-to-write-a-book):

> Please clarify what "higher secondary level book" means. – scaaahu Jul 31 at 4:03

and [on this copy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47503/how-to-help-a-postgraduate-student-to-write-a-book):

> I'm kind of confused by your terminology. What does "completed his/her post-graduation" mean - did this person finish a degree? Masters? PhD? About this result - is this about a thesis that was weaker than hoped? What is a "passive teacher"? – Nate Eldredge Jun 20 at 4:05

You've also posted this question on other SE sites, such as History of Science and Mathematics. There, too, you were asked to clarify the question and didn't. (They tried to [migrate it to Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48142/how-to-help-a-postgraduate-student-to-write-a-book), but of course it was closed there again.) Same thing on [Quantitative finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21438/how-to-help-a-postgraduate-student-to-write-a-book) (!). Google search results suggest you've also asked it on SciFi and Fantasy, Philosophy, Information Security, Freelancing, [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/617/how-to-help-a-postgraduate-student-to-write-a-book) and probably other sites as well.

Instead of responding to comments, you delete your account each time you post this question, so that you can't clarify your post.

**In its current state** this question cannot be answered *anywhere.* If you want an answer, you should stop deleting your account immediately after posting the question, be responsive to comments, and edit your post to add information that others ask for in comments.

After all that, it may or may not be on topic somewhere in the SE network. (We can't tell right now because nobody can understand the question.) But if you keep posting the same thing *as is* over and over on all different sites without clarifying it as requested (and continuing to respond to requests for clarification), you'll never know. It will just **keep being closed everywhere you post it**.

Comment: @Satyajay There are a lot of things that are unclear about the question. If you ever post it again, you need to (1) include in the post *all* the clarifications that users have previously asked you to make, AND (2) stick around and *keep* clarifying as users ask more questions in comments. Keep engaging with your question, don't delete your account, and edit/respond to comments on the post instead of just posting it again.

Comment: I just came across this. The OP is *still* trying to post this question, with no improvements - now on [literature.se] and [writers.se], among others.

Comment: This post was also the subject of [this MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260301/162102).  We've deleted at least a dozen copies on Writers.  The poster often includes a comment linking to the question (reason uknown), and always self-deletes the account right after.  It's very difficult to grant the benefit of the doubt here.

Comment: The pattern of these posts has been added to [SmokeDetector](http://charcoal-se.org/#whats-smokey), and today we were able to delete another instance [a few minutes after it was posted](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/57563).

Comment: [This metasmoke search](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=help+a+postgraduate&body=&username=&why=&site=&feedback=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search) will give you a bit of an idea of the amount of exact duplicates that have been caught so far.